# How are topology optimizations validated?

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, verification

How are topology optimizations validated?

I've been confused. Doesn't this mean that each of such design (e.g. N=100) would still need to be validated empirically or is there something that allows one to understand the validity of several of such models?

Comment: Wouldn't it be enough to use your forward solver to 'verify' that it is correct? Why is this not enough?

Comment: @Nachiket But how many models must one compare? A topology optimizer could, I think, easily produce 100 designs. Will one build all of those?

Answer (score 4):

I think that you are mixing two different concepts: verification and validation.

If your forward solver has been verified it means that it is *solving the equations right*. If you have validated it, you are *solving the right equations*. In terms of an optimizer, you have an optimal solution if it satisfies the constraints and it attains a lower (or higher) value than other evaluated designs.

Now, you are mentioning that you could end up with 100 designs that have the same value for the objective function. In terms of validation/verification they are all equal (assuming that you have validated/verified beforehand). The question might be how to choose from those... but I would say that is not a verification question.